# Is it possible to Cluster Non-float data in KMeans in Python(Scikit-Learn)?

Tags: python, arrays, machine-learning, k-means

I am trying to apply KMeans(Scikit-learn) on below mentioned data. 
[image: Data]
.

I have seen enough example where Float64 values are shown in cluster. What I would like to know is If clustering is possible on column df[[Description ]], having the x and y axis as Longitude and Latitude.

My code looks like this.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import pandas as pd
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

df = pd.read_csv('df.csv')

encoder =LabelEncoder()
Longitude = encoder.fit_transform(df.Longitude)
Latitude= df[df.columns[19]].values #(latitude)

x=np.array([Longitude, Latitude]).T

est = KMeans(3)

est.fit(df[['Longitude', 'Latitude', 'Description']])
```

But the error I get on this line is

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 est.fit(df[['Longitude', 'Latitude', 'Description']])
>
> c:\users\magiri\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\k_means_.py
>   in fit(self, X, y)
>       878         """
>       879         random_state = check_random_state(self.random_state)
>   --> 880         X = self._check_fit_data(X)
>       881 
>       882         self.cluster_centers_, self.labels_, self.inertia_, self.n_iter_ = \
>
> c:\users\magiri\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\k_means_.py
>   in _check_fit_data(self, X)
>       852     def _check_fit_data(self, X):
>       853         """Verify that the number of samples given is larger than k"""
>   --> 854         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr', dtype=[np.float64, np.float32])
>       855         if X.shape[0] < self.n_clusters:
>       856             raise ValueError("n_samples=%d should be >= n_clusters=%d" % (
>
> c:\users\magiri\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py
>   in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy,
>   force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples,
>   ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
>       380                                       force_all_finite)
>       381     else:
>   --> 382         array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
>       383 
>       384         if ensure_2d:
>
> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'GAME/DICE'

So, what I want to know is df.Description cluster with reference to Longitude and Latitude. I know Description column has string values which is why I am getting the error. Is there anyway I can avoid this error and can see clustering of Description column.

Comment: If you have structured data, you probably wanna use some other clustering algorithm which support `precomputed` metrics, and you compute your metric matrix and pass it along.

Answer (score 3):

K-mean algorithm only works with numeric data. You could apply `OneHotEncoder` to your "Description" and "Location Description" fields to transform it one-hot-encoded representation. If your Description has some hierarchical values using `CountVectorizer` with a custom tokenizer could also be worth trying.

To make sure Lattitude / Longitude doesn't outweigh the other fields in the Euclidean distance you can apply  `StandardScaler` on your data prior to K-means.

Comment: Thanks. Since, it can't cluster anything other than numeric data. K-means probably won't be right approach for me.

Comment: @ManeetGiri All clustering algorithms work with numeric data. If you have text data, you can transform it to an array of numbers either with `LabelEncoder` (if you have a finite amount of categories) or a `CountVectorizer` (for general text), which can then be provided to K-means (or or any other clustering algorihtm).

Comment: Note that `LabelEncoder` is not supposed to be used with input (`X`). It's designed to handle output (`y`) only.

Comment: @adrin Yes, thanks this was a really old answer. Edited to correct.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully used kmodes and kprototypes to cluster categorical data. There is a python implementation here:  https://github.com/nicodv/kmodes. Kmodes allows clustering categorical data and kprototypes clusters both categorical and numerical data (a mix of kmeans and kmodes). Sample usage from the github page

```
import numpy as np
from kmodes.kmodes import KModes

# random categorical data
data = np.random.choice(20, (100, 10))

km = KModes(n_clusters=4, init='Huang', n_init=5, verbose=1)

clusters = km.fit_predict(data)

# Print the cluster centroids
print(km.cluster_centroids_)
```

Kmodes simply clusters based on common categories between points. A simplified summary of the distance measure for kprototypes is

```
distance = np.sum((a_num - b_num) ** 2) + gamma * np.sum(a_cat != b_cat)
```

where `a_num` and `b_num` are the numerical values of two points, and `a_cat` and `b_cat` are the categorical values. `gamma` is a weighting of the cost of categorical differences versus numerical distance. The default value is half the standard deviation of the numerical features (=0.5 if normalising numerical features beforehand).